# How to configure Tailwind Intellisense to work with temp files from WinSCP?

Tags: visual-studio-code, configuration, tailwind-css, intellisense, winscp

I am trying to setup the Tailwind CSS Intellisense (by Tailwind Labs) VSCode extension to work with files that get temporary downloaded from an ftp server through WinSCP when I start editing. They are simple index.html files.

The extension works completely fine with a normally created html file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: for the sake of absolute clarity, where are these files downloaded to on your machine, and what are their file extensions?